# Ionic 4 Angular 6 create app not asking Cordova Integration question

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic, and just installed it and i also installed Cordova on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, then i used the command to create an app using these commands

```
npm install -g ionic
npm install -g cordova
```

then i used the command to create an app using these

```
ionic start ionic4Tut --type=angular
```

**but I'm not** getting the question about integrating cordova to the project as shown in all the tutorials,

```
Integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? (y/N)
```

anyone know way is that?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem and what I did was after creating the project using

```
$ionic start projName --type=angular
```

I will cd to my project folder and run

```
$ionic cordova platform
```

that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova is what the Ionic framework uses to target native functionality for mobile devices. It does this because Ionic is primarily a mobile app framework. If you don't want to integrate it and want to use nothing but the development framework, you may as well use Angular on it's own.

Reference: [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)

Comment: I do want to use Cordova, its only that when i create the app using the commands i wort on the question i don't get the question about it/

Comment: If you want to use Cordova, press "Y" on your keyboard and then hit enter to continue.

Comment: The problem is that i don't get the question during the app creation process!

Comment: Oh man I'm sorry, I didn't read that right at all.

Uninstall and reinstall ionic. That should fix it.